# Is there a way to check if the char is printable for Data.Text?

Tags: haskell

There is an "isprint" in Data.Char which just calls a C function.

Now I have a bunch of Text from Data.Text needs to be filtered by this. Is there an efficient way? Or I have to convert Text to String?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function would have a signature of

```
(Char -> Bool) -> Text -> Text
```

So, [asking Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=(Char+-%3E+Bool)+-%3E+Text+-%3E+Text) we find [Data.Text.filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html#v:filter):

```
filter :: (Char -> Bool) -> Text -> Text
```

Or if you wanted to ensure all the characters in the string are printable, let's [ask for](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28Char+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+Text+-%3E+Bool)...

```
(Char -> Bool) -> Text -> Bool
```

And find [Data.Text.all](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text.html#v:all):

```
all :: (Char -> Bool) -> Text -> Bool
```

Comment: So Char is involved any way. I can see the filter func, just wondering if there is a more directly way. Thanks.

Comment: @Magicloud: What would you prefer to write, over `T.filter isPrint t` / `T.all isPrint t`? (Assuming `import qualified Data.Text as T` and `t :: Text`.) I guess if you’re going to use this operation in multiple places, you can factor it out into a function, e.g. `onlyPrint = T.filter isPrint` then use `onlyPrint t`.

Comment: @Magicloud Not likely there is a specialised function for that.

Comment: @Magicloud Of course `Char` is involved; `Text` is a sequence of `Char`s.